# Assembler- reading bits

Tags: assembly, stdin, bit

anyone could help me read 96 bits from user in assembly?
For now I was reading numbers like this:

```
mov $12, %edx
mov $variable1, %ecx
mov $STDIN, %ebx
mov $SYSREAD, %eax
int $0x80
```

Can anyone help me reforge this code, so I can read bits instead of bytes?
I have to add 2 numbers of 96 bits- maybe I read it correctly, but later use them wrong?

Comment: You haven't said anything about which format the user should enter the numbers in (decimal, hex, binary, base64, ...).

Comment: The professor said only that I have to read string of bits

Answer (score 0):

96/16 = 6 words or 3 dwords

You can shove it onto the stack then load each chunk(16 or 32 bit) via a pop to, say eax

Then use shl in a loop

```
 mov cx,32  ;The 32 bit loop

 .printbinary
 shl eax,1      ;shove eax one bit to the left
 jnc azero      ;jump if no carry flag
 PRINT A ONE    
 loop printbinary
 .azero
 PRINT A ZERO
 loop printbinary
```

kinda thing

(Whatever it is you're trying to do, the carry flag reads individual bits and shr/shl moves the register 1 bit)

A screen dump etc will only give you hex codes

So print out the lines of binary one over the other onscreen (96 times each???)
Then use ADD for bignumbers in your particular flavour of language
Then print out the 96 digit answer underneath...lol

(I don't even know if its possible to get 96 digits into one line, don't forget, theres no carriage return or linefeed until you've printed the entire string)